# ActiveMQ Artemis AMQ219016 and AMQ219006 when consuming/producing messages

Tags: jms, micronaut, activemq-artemis

We have an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 with a queue and producer which sometimes fails with following error: `AMQ219006: Channel disconnected` and right after `AMQ219016: Connection failure detected. Unblocking a blocking call that will never get a response`. I have read different resources on this error and cannot figure out what could be causing it.
Could this be caused by a high throughput on the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Neither `AMQ219006` nor `AMQ219016` can be resolved with a "high availability" (i.e. HA) configuration. The underlying cause for these messages is explained on the [answer you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815155/activemq-artemis-producer-fails-with-jmsexception-amq219016). HA won't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

How do you identify a message being the right one / being the next one? If it is a custom message property, you could skip this consuming and putting back messages cycle by using a message selector (specifying the expected value for this property) to consume the right message right away. If it is not a message property, might it be feasible to redesign and let the producer of the message add this ordering information into such a custom message property?
This won't avoid receiving the error situations you describe entirely. But it seems you are doing plenty of potentially redundant queuing activity due to your application design, which also increases the risk you are within a transaction which cannot be continued when a failover occurs on broker level leading to the exceptions you currently face occasionally.